# Re-ask: Get all the VBA macros of a workbook by JavaScript API for Excel

Tags: vba, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I would like to re-ask a question I asked more than 2 years ago: **Can JavaScript API for Office get VBA macros that a document contains?** ([UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/14062119-enable-fetching-vba-macros-of-a-workbook-in-javasc))

Both VBA and VSTO have access to VBA macros. Tools such as [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html) could extrait `vbaProject.bin`; Moreover, tools like [olevba.py](https://github.com/decalage2/oletools/blob/master/oletools/olevba.py) could decompress even `vbaProject.bin`.

If an Office document contains VBA code, it is probably an important component. Some big companies have in-house tools to inspect their VBA macros against bad programming practices, code smells, malware, computer forensics. There are software to measure metrics of VBA macros and find bugs. All these functionalities would be impossible without access to VBA macros.

I guess providing an JavaScript API to read VBA macros would not be too complicated, but it could make possible many features and JavaScript add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible to do today. Web add-ins are a multiplatform concept meaning all APIs exposed in JavaScript most function across all platforms (namely Windows, Online, Mac, iOS). Given that macros are not a multiplatform concept they are not exposed in our JS API.

Comment: Is there any planned future functionality that might expose these VBAs to the API in contexts where they do exist?

Given that APIs are versioned and have feature sets, this seems like a natural extension. Having access to VBA modules would be super helpful! Specifically, trying to write an add-on that detects changes from versions of VBA code.